# Position absolute inside scrollable parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV container and DIV.right with this code. The DIV.right takes place on the right but when the container has overflow-x set to `scroll` and I scroll — the div scrolls too. I don't want the right DIV to scroll with the content. How to achieve this?

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p style="height: 200vh;">Long text to force scrollbars...</p>
  <div class="right">
    Right should not scroll
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry i didn't put them in my comment but i have them in my code

Comment: I've edited your question. Please next time do the same. Try to be clear and create always (if feasible) a [mcve] that clearly presents the issue you're facing with the minimal code necessary to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `position:sticky` but the order of `right` div and the `p` tag will be changed!

```css
.container {
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.right {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
Example
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    Right should not scroll
  </div>
  <p style="height: 200vh;">Long text to force scrollbars...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you explain I understand that you want the right div to stay in a fixed place on the page, so you can do this:

```
.right{ 
     position: fixed,
     top: 0,
     right: 0,
}
```

Position `fixed` will not move when the page is being scrolled, while absolute will do move since its relative to its parent location (which are moving when scrolling)